# Combining two tables with fkey relationship

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to join two tables which are only related on another table (3rd table) and the identity of the two tables are foreign key of the 3rd table.  Please refer to the image below so that I can fully describe what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

Relationship specs:

- Actual.Id = Actual x Budget.Id
- Budget.Id = Actual x Budget.Id
- Budget.DateField = Actuals x Budget.DateField
- And the last relationship: They are assigned as same data on **Actual x
  Budget.ColA**

Is this achievable or should I change my database schema?

Comment: I don't follow exactly, you have both keys concatenated in a single column in the 3rd table, or are they separate columns?

Comment: By the way, you are looking at a `JOIN` operation which is very common.

Comment: Hi, I just updated the question, I forgot to attach the image.  Yes, I know a little bit of join clauses.  But it doesn't seem to work with just piling up the inner/join clauses.  Or I am doing something wrong.

Comment: in short, yes. I'll explain in my response

Comment: I don't understand the database layout. Maybe you can explain what these tables represent? What is Actual? What is Budget? How are they related (I mean business-like not technical)?

Answer (score 0):

For your ActualXBudget table, don't use a single field for ID's from BOTH actual and budget. Use two columns, one for budgetID and one for ActualID. That way, a single row from ActualXBudget will be linked to both budget and Actual.

With your design, the DB has no idea that Budget ID 4 = Actual ID 1.

With Actual ID and Budget ID in the ActualXBudget Table, you can do simple joins to both tables and pull out attached records, like

```
SELECT Actual.ColA,Actual.ColB,Budget.ColB,Budget.ColC FROM
(Actual INNER JOIN ActualXBudget ON Actual.ID = ActualXBudget.ActualID)
INNER JOIN Budget ON Budget.ID = ActualXBudget.BudgetID
```

Edit: With your setup you could do

```
 SELECT Actual.ColA,Actual.ColB,Budget.ColB,Budget.ColC FROM
 (Actual INNER JOIN ActualXBudget ON Actual.ID = ActualXBudget.ID )
 INNER JOIN Budget ON Budget.DateField = ActualXBudget.DateField
```

but don't do that.